# Is it possible to have same SYSDATETIME result for 2 transactions

Tags: sql-server-2012

According to documentation, the precision of SYSDATETIME() function in sql server is approximately 100 nanoseconds. <strike>I have seen that just like GETDATE(), the SYSDATETIME function also returns the same result within a transaction.</strike> Also, the time differs in two batches separated by GO.
Now my real question is, is it safe to assume that two transactions will always have different SYSDATETIME, no matter how close to concurrency they can reach within the same server/database instance, irrespective of the number of cores/hardware, the server has? 
Background: I am trying to implement audit on an existing database using temporal tables. We are already keeping a modified by column in all tables. But we cannot identify who deleted a record using temporal tables. So I was thinking of dumping user id (end user's id) into a table for all transactions. So, if the time matches with temporal table, I might be able to identify the user based on date-time.

Comment: please see my answer. hope it will help you in your query.

Comment: My test was not correct. getdate is indeed changing over multiple statements within same transaction. So I cannot rely on any date functions alone to identify a transaction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First i need to inform you that `GETDATE()` and `SYSDATETIME` gives the different datetime formate. `SYSDATETIME()` will give you result as follow - `2019-06-03 16:11:07.3683245` and `GETDATE()` will - `2019-06-03 16:11:07.367`. Now the things is you need to add two columns in a table for which user updated the records and what time. And if you are not using any time consuming process between update temporal table and update main table than it will get same time both. But if any reason it will take time to update both record than it can be different time in both table.

You can use `Declare` method in `sql` to have same `datetime` in both table. No problem when it will update at different time. you can use `Declare` method to get `datetime` same as like follow.

```
Declare @date Datetime2 = SYSDATETIME()
Select @Date
```

You can use @Date When you are updating `datetime` in query.

I hope it will work.

Comment: I do the same within same procedure to make sure all the insert/updates are having same time. But my intention was to identify the person who deleted a row by minimal change in existing procedures by somehow linking with the deleted record in history table.

Comment: if you want to save the records in history table than you may use triggers. it is easy to use and you will get all history of every records which has been modified.

Comment: System versioned temporal doesn't requires us to create separate tables for keeping history. And we try to avoid triggers where ever possible.